# what's your favourite sound design / musictech / pro audio magazine? 

Tags: magazine, resources

i'm frequently reading the famous Sound On Sound... but noticed it's only about 30% of the content there which i find interesting... it's too gear-oriented, almost like reading a tech manual sometimes. i'm looking for something that combines gear reviews, technique and also some conceptual stuff, audio art, interviews, etc. any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Social Sound Design 
:-)

Answer (score 1):

I like Mix magazine quite a bit

Answer (score 1):

I read Resolution and AudioMedia

Answer (score 1):

TapeOp

Signal to Noise

Answer (score 1):

The [Soundworks Collection](http://soundworkscollection.com/) usually yields some interesting and inspirational content from professionals in the film world.

Answer (score 0):

Mix, SSD, Designing Sound, Sound Works, Audiomedia. The net is a great way for me to network and find out what other people are doing. It has become so exciting.